# Is it possible to separately plug in OpenMP libraries to Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, openmp

In Visual Studio **2005**. OpenMP didn't come with the Express Edition, but it was possible to download it separately and get it set up, since the compiler itself was OMP-enabled.

Is the same true with Visual Studio **2008**? We are all using Standard Edition which similarly supports OpenMP but doesn't come with the libs/headers. Some code we have uses OMP but we don't really want the big cost of upgrading our licenses just for OMP. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you seriously asking for help on how to break your license agreement?  It is quite explicit in the EULA, you can't work around the license restrictions.

Comment: Are you sure? It is documented by _MS themselves_ how to get MFC working with VC++ Express for instance, which is a similar case where the libraries don't come with the Express version. If you think what I want is breaking the license, please post a proper answer citing sources, for future readers to find with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can *get a hold of* the files `omp.h`, its corresponding library files `vcomp.lib`, `vcompd.lib` and the redistributable libraries which correspond to the libs (the directory with the DLLs and the manifest) then there's nothing to stop you from linking to them and using them.

The files probably need to match exactly to the version of VS you have. i.e. it probably matters if you have 2008 or 2008 SP1.

Comment: So, where can I get these? Do MS make this available as a part of any SDK perhaps?

Answer (score -3):

I think that you can include the `#pragma omp` directive and use the `/openmp` flag during the compilation process in VS 2008.

Details here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx

Comment: I know how to use OpenMP. It doesn't work, because the header <omp.h> and the libraries are not supplied with VS2008 Express/Standard.